# Determine whether $f(Z(G))\subset SL_n(F)$, where $f$ is a representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $F$ a field, and $f:G\to GL_n(F)$ a representation. Determine whether $f(Z(G))\subset SL_n(F)$, where $Z(G)$ denotes the center of $G$.

I am a beginner in representation theory. I can use a hint. What action is being represented? If that action was conjugation, then the corresponding matrix representation would be the $n\times n$ identity matrix, so that the image under $f$ would be contained in $SL_n$. However, I don't know whether this is remotely close to what is needed, and I wouldn't know how to modify the argument if one replaced $Z(G)$ with another group (such as the commutator subgroup). Can my argument be modified to show $f(Z(G))\subset SL_n(F)$?

Comment: Is it possible that $F$ is the real or complex numbers? If so, this is much more answerable.

Comment: If you have input for that case I'd like to see it.

Comment: For $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb Q$, matrices of finite order have determinant 1 or -1.

Answer (score 1):

The representation is not specified here, so it could be anything. Because of this, there isn't a single answer.

If $F$ is a finite field, for example, then there are many finite subgroups of $SL(n,F)$ and $G$ could just be one of these, with the inclusion map being the representation.

There are also plenty of (finite) abelian subgroups of $GL(n,F)$ that are not contained in $SL(n,F)$. Or for that matter if $G=GL(n,F)$ then the scalar matrices are in the center of $G$ but generally do not lie in $SL(n,F)$.

So the answer to the question very much depends on the representation. Sometimes the central elements will act with determinant 1 but they don't need to.

If this question came from a textbook on introductory representation theory, I would suspect that there was a typo or something missing. I think more details need to be added to the question to get a meaningful straightforward answer.